# Area of rectangle of the following image

Tags: triangles, area, rectangles

[image]

With the right triangle EMT has 5,12, and 13 of length.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The "problem statement" seems to rely on unstated assumptions about the diagram.  The title refers to "Area of rectangle" but no identification of which figure is *the* rectangle appears in the body of the Question.  The body text should be used to give a clear and complete formulation of the problem you want help with. The Accepted Answer assumes $AYST$, the colored region in the image, is a rectangle whose area is sought, but it cannot be inferred simply from the right triangle $EMT$ and its dimensions that the image contains any rectangles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Euclid's theorem, we have:
$$\overline{OT}=\frac{\overline{TM}^2}{\overline{EM}}=\frac{25}{13}$$
Let $\alpha=\angle{TEM}$, we have:
$$\sin(\alpha)=\frac{5}{13} \land \cos(\alpha)=\frac{12}{13}$$
Now, the triangle $OAT$ is a right triangle with hypotenuse $OT$, and so:
$$\overline{AT}=\overline{OT}\cdot\sin(\alpha)=\frac{125}{169}$$
Observing $ST$, we can say:
$$\overline{ST}=\overline{ET}-\overline{ES}=\overline{ET}-\overline{OT}\cdot\cos(\alpha)=13-\frac{300}{169}=\frac{1897}{169}$$
Finally, the area of $AYST$ is:
$$\overline{ST}\cdot\overline{AT}=\frac{125}{169}\cdot\frac{1897}{169}=\frac{237125}{28561}$$